# default view for tablet users - chat.so

Tags: feature-request, chat, mobile-web, ipad

Would it be possible to set `mobile=false` as the default for visitors with iPads or other tablets that can handle the normal mode of [chat.stackoverflow](https://chat.stackoverflow.com)?  Or at least set a cookie when I select the "non-mobile" view (via the chat room menu at the bottom of the page)? The mobile version of chat is quite limited and iPad's can view the regular site just fine.  Manually adding `?mobile=false` to each url on every [chat.so](https://chat.stackoverflow.com) page I visit is no fun ;).

Comment: This was already done for [the main site](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81165/dont-use-mobile-theme-on-ipad)

Comment: @MichaelMrozek Super glad about that, too!  That would drive me crazy if it defaulted to mobile. I actually dont know of many sites that still lump iPads in with iPhones in their rewrites.

Comment: There are no rewrites. That said, unfortunately the iPad browser used to have some ... issues. But I'll have another look. It definitely works fine in the Honyecomb browser, so we'll probably do this for Android tablets.

Comment: @balpha chat on the iPad non-mobile view still has issues.

Comment: @JackDouglas It sure does.