# Mobile theme has returned on my iPad

Tags: support, ipad, mobile-web

Reference: [Don't use mobile theme on iPad](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81165/dont-use-mobile-theme-on-ipad)

This was ok for a while, but just this morning I started getting the mobile theme on stackoverflow.com on my iPad again.

I have an iPad 1, and I recently upgraded it to iOS 5 -- but I was getting the regular theme after the upgrade until today.  (I had the site open in the browser with the regular theme, but I got the mobile theme when I reloaded or opened a link.)

Did something break in the last day or so?

And is there a way to select the mobile theme vs. the regular theme, regardless of what device you're using?  (Yeah, that's two questions.)

Comment: Can't you specify which to use in iSafari or iWhatever?  I know I can specify a moble/desktop preference *on my windows 7 phone.*  Perhaps the update added this option (if it wasn't there before) and now you have to configure it?

Comment: Two downvotes a day apart.  There must be some reason for that.  Would someone care to enlighten me?  Is it because I asked two questions?

Comment: Downvotes are different on meta.  However, I'd suspect people downvoted because it was a simple answer.

Comment: @Won'tಠ_ಠ: I understand that downvotes are different on meta.  But it was a real problem that I ran into, others may also run into it, and the solution (workaround?) isn't entirely obvious.  (And I still think that something changed on the site to trigger the problem; it's possible that I accidentally tapped the "mobile" link on the footer, but I don't think I did.)  Oh, well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And is there a way to select the mobile theme vs. the regular theme, regardless of what device you're using?

Yup, there's a link in the footer.

[image]

[image]