# Site theme for tablets

Tags: feature-request, mobile-web, design

On tablets, the mobile theme for Stack Exchange sites is overly simplistic. However, there's a lot to the full site that is difficult to use or overly crowded on a tablet, and some things require mouseovers.

Could we have another theme specifically for tablet devices?

Comment: Yay for responsive design.

Comment: For the record, "touchscreen" and "mouseover" is not a contradiction. I exclusively use the non-mobile site even on my phone. (This is not meant to invalidate your request in general)

Comment: @balpha No, it's not, but it's so much harder to use on a touchscreen.

Comment: @balpha: If there's a way to do mouseover on an iPad, I'd like to know about it.  Likewise for other touchscreen mobile devices.

Comment: @KeithThompson About 50% of the time, tapping will work. The other 50%, it won't.

Comment: @KeithThompson I don't know about the iPad. In the Android browser, just touching something (e.g. sliding your finger over it) causes a hover event.

Comment: Sorry Timothy, we're unable to grant you this request because it appears you're not a hippopotamus. We apologize for any inconveniences this may cause. ;-)

Comment: @TheUnhandledException Haha, nice.

Comment: @balpha Not on the iPad. I guess that's one of the few disadvantages I concede of iPad to Android tablets!

Comment: What essential feature of the full site requires hovering? Like balpha, I regularly use the non-mobile site, but I have an iPhone. I've never missed the ability to hover. Sure you don't get little niceties like tooltips, but I've been around long enough I know what the widgets do.

Comment: @TheEstablishment Examples: rating/flagging/editing/deleting comments; showing the drop down menu accessed via one's username (you can click the arrow, but it's tiny).

Comment: Hmm, yeah I guess I don't use that user name drop-down thingadongdong. But on the iPhone, all I have to do is tap the comment and the vote controls show up.

Answer (score 1):

Please, for the love of all that is holy, no. We've been [down this road before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/81165/149432) and I really, really don't want to go back. Mobile Safari on iPad is a fully-featured browser on a 10-inch screen: it does not need to have a stripped-down, feature-lagged version of the website (which is, let's face it, what "tablet" versions inevitably are).

In the comments, [balpha mentioned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126973/site-theme-for-tablets#comment344617_126973) that,

> In the Android browser, just touching something (e.g. sliding your finger over it) causes a hover event.

And [you claimed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126973/site-theme-for-tablets#comment344648_126973) that this is not the case on iPad: you're mistaken. If you tap an element with a mouseover event that triggers a content change, iPad *does*, in fact, [react to that event](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html). The only trick or gotcha is that quick taps work better: long, deliberate taps will generally tend to register as a click event.

Having used the full version of Stack Exchange on iPad for the past year, the only two things that are unavailable are:

- Tooltips generated by the `title` attribute (e.g., timestamps and help text, both completely unessential to using the site)
- Spoiler markdown (which can actually be fixed with [a slight change in implementation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/104029/149432) that [should be in the desktop version anyway](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1191/add-markdown-support-for-hidden-until-you-click-text-aka-spoilers/71396#comment172043_71396))

In conclusion, every time a site needlessly has a tablet version (or worse, defaults to its mobile version when it detects a tablet; but that's beside the point), a puppy cries.

[image: Puppy]
<sup>by [23am.com on Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/23am/3817278904/), CC-BY-SA</sup>

Please, think of the puppies: leave browsing on tablets alone.

Comment: While I understand not wanting to remove features, I'm not asking for that. I just want to be able to view and interact with the full site without having to zoom in and out all the time. It's hard to tap small things, like comment vote buttons for example, without zooming in quite far. All I want is a slightly-re*designed* interface, not a drastically different one.

Answer (score 0):

Please, with bigger buttons (especially the comment voting and flagging buttons are too small)!

Perhaps also larger fonts in the edit areas than for preview and content, since touch has to be used when editing.

Some of the mouseovers should also be made into toggles IMO (see exact time of a post, for example).