# iPad Stackoverflow user interface problem

Tags: bug, views, feedback, ipad

I use an iPad to visit Stackoverflow. Stack overflow is simply THE best Q&A website I have ever come across. But the problem I face is every time I visit stack overflow I am presented with a desktop view. And I believe there is only one view.

In the desktop view, when I try to comment or touch anything in an answer, I am first presented with the feedback asking me if I found the answer helpful. Then I have to touch again to complete my action.

Please, it would be a great help if the administrators created another tablet-friendly view be ause in the desktop mode, the feedback appears at every hover over an answer.

Note: I *am* logged in on SO.

Comment: For me, it is fine on iPad and the usual view; however, if you scroll down to the bottom, do you see a "mobile" link (next to "contact us")? If so, can you click it?

Comment: hmmm... I wonder if this only happens at rep below the voting threshold - I'll need to play with data on dev to find out...

Comment: @Marc yep, try this when logged out. Clicking _anywhere_ on a post brings up the feedback form. See the update to my post below, I've explained the bug further.

Comment: @Marc I've always had this issue (I use my iPad to view the full version (desktop) of Stackoverflow), both before I registered (very recently) and now (I only have 6 rep). Clinking a link in a different answer seems to "reset" the effect, meaning the first link click in a different answer brings up the "Was this post useful to you" feedback question.

Answer (score 3):

Update:I realised what you're talking about, and managed to repro (on Terra and Safari--though I investigated on Terra)

Devs: the bug is as follows:

Whenever logged out (or possibly when you have less rep), if you try clicking *any* link on a post, it first shows the feedback buttons. Clicking *again* makes it work. This includes: links in the post, links in the comments, the [link] link, [improve this answer], usercard links, "edited x minutes ago", tags, and the vote button (on the second click the vote button gives the "login to vote" thingy)

Note that this happens in a mix-and-match manner. On the first click on a post, the feedback form shows up, but the click is absorbed. Once the feedback form is up on a post, *all the links work, not just the one you clicked*. You can make the feedback form go away by clicking on another post.

Since it doesn't work in *two* iPad browsers, I suspect it has to do with `mousedown` and `click` and `mouseover` interfering with the event bubbling--tablets deal with these events in a confusing(yet necessary) manner.

---

<s>I can't reproduce this (iPad 1, iOS 5.latest-whatever-it-is).</s>

If the feedback form shows up, you're not logged in. Is your username there at the top of the page?

You can always switch to the mobile view via the link at the bottom of the page.

See also: [Site theme for tablets](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126973/site-theme-for-tablets)

Also, [you shouldn't be able to comment anyway (except on your own post)](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment) till you get 50 rep.

Comment: I am asking a question - I hope that suffices my credentials.

Comment: And yes, I do have my name at the top

Comment: @c.adhityaa: I'm talking about when you're logged in to SO. Currently you're logged in to MSO, but it's not necessary that SO will log you in. Go here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10296014/appmarket-in-android-x86 and tell me if your name is on top. If it is, and trying to comment still shows the feedback form, then we have a problem.

Comment: Yes, at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10296014/appmarket-in-android-x86 I see my name at the top and, unfortunately, the feedback form at the bottom of a post.

Comment: @c.adhityaa: Strange.

Comment: Will the admins do something about it ?

Comment: @c.adhityaa: You'll have to wait for them to have a look at it. I think this is just a Safari bug, nothing more.

Comment: @c.adhityaa first we need to understand it! I use SO on iPad regularly, and have never had that problem.

Comment: I tested this on my iPad and get this issue using Safari and Chrome, but not when using Opera Mini.